# Pass the current class as parameter

Tags: php, class, parameter-passing, self-reference

I have a class like this:

```
// file /models/person.php
class Person 
{
    public function create_path()
    {
         self::log();
         path_helper($this);  //a global function in other php file
    }

    public function log()
    {
         echo "trying to create a path";
    }

}
```

This is the way how `Person` is instanciated:

```
//file /tools/Builder.php
include('/models/Person.php');
class Builder
{
    public function build()
    {
        $type = 'Person';
        $temp = new $type();
        $temp->create_path();
    } 
}
```

As you note in Person class, I am calling the object in question with `$this` reference. But this is not correct because an error is showed:

> Message: Undefined variable: this

I suppose that `$this` reference point to other object or it is unable to work because the object is created from another script. Also, I tried to use `self` because there was not problem calling methods with that, but as parameter I get:

> Message: Use of undefined constant self - assumed 'self'

So, can you guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code out for myself, with a few minor changes. It appears to work properly.

- Changed `self::log()` to `$this->log()`
- Added global function `path_helper` (I have no idea what this does)

**PHP**

```
function path_helper(Person $object)
{
    var_dump($object);
}
class Person 
{
    public function create_path()
    {
         $this->log();
         path_helper($this);  //a global function in other php file
    }

    public function log()
    {
         echo "trying to create a path";
    }

}
class Builder
{
    public function build()
    {
        $type = 'Person';
        $temp = new $type();
        $temp->create_path();
    } 
}

$Build = new Builder();
$Build->build();
```

**Result**

```
trying to create a path

object(Person)[2]
```

Your code is correct and your going in the right direction.

Comment: No my friend, calling `$this` inside of a method prints the error as I mencioned, but if it works at your side there is something else that I need to review

Comment: @manix. Interesting. What version of PHP are you using? We could have an issue popping up there. I'm on 5.4.3. Passing `$this` back and forth is how you accomplish tasks like method chaining. So, a version issue is all I can think of.

Comment: @manix, There are significant differences between 5.3 and 5.4 in terms of OOP. I do not have time this moment, but if your question is unanswered later, I'll load up 5.3 and figure it out for you.

Comment: cool!  I will be working on it the entire day. Since now thank you so much for time and help.  Let me know if you will need more detailt about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the log method like this:

```
$this->log();
```

because using self:: is reserved for static methods.

Also, try calling the path_helper function like this:

```
path_helper(self);
```

Hope I could help you. Couldn't test it, but it should work.